# Upgrade SONAR: The results change

Tags: sonarqube

We launched sonar 4.5.4 in one of our application. Then, we have upgraded sonar with 6.7.5 version and we have got different results.

e.g.: the rule DLS_DEAD_LOCAL_STORE. When we passed our code with 4.5.4 version, this critical rule was not broken at all. With the new version, it appears as a new critical bug even when no changes have been implemented (last commit for this classes was made more than one year ago).

Is there any documentation about rule implementation changes per versions?

Does anyone any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade SonarQube you have to prepare yourself for some (big) changes. There is a large gap between 4.5.4 and 6.7.5 so, do not be surprised that checkers have been enhanced and severity revised.

It is normal and you should analyze changes before performing any application upgrade.